# AJAX Post with multiple parameter to Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to do an ajax post request with multiple parameters. The method is called on server side but the parameters returns null. What am I doing wrong here? I've tried with and without JSON.stringify.

.cs file:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostGenerate(string fname, string lname)
{
    return new JsonResult(fname + lname);
}
```

AJAX script:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Index?handler=Generate",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    headers: {
        RequestVerificationToken:
            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({
        fname: "testFirstname",
        lname: "testLastname"
    }),
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to change

```
data: JSON.stringify({
        fname: "testFirstname",
        lname: "testLastname"
    }),
```

to

```
data: {
        "fname": "testFirstname",
        "lname": "testLastname"
    },
```

and remove

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Comment: My pleasure.Can you accept it as an answer？